# Data filled in the creation of the document are not transferred to the library

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-online, form, irm

I am using SharePoint Online.

I have a library with IRM enabled. This list has several columns, among them metadata columns. This library only works with Content Types, users can not upload other file types.

Each time a user creates a file in the client's own word he can fill the form with the columns of the library, but when the file is saved and checked-in information is lost and not going to list columns.

Anyone have any idea can be happening?

Update:Only the metadata columns not receive the informatrion.

Comment: How many content types are associateed to the list? Check whether the content type you selected while opening word is the default one

Comment: Exist 10 content types in this library. And yes, he is the content type default.

Comment: did you try opening the document again and see whther the metadata values you saved is available in the document properties

Comment: All are blank, man.